# Simplify regression model equation to a more readable form

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I'm currently working with [Binfords Constructing Frames of Reference](http://www.ucpress.edu/book.php?isbn=9780520223936) and came across this model equation:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:area_multi}
\begin{aligned}
\mathit{AREA} = & 10 ** [3.421431 + \\ 
                & (0.004732 * \mathit{HUNTING}) + \\
                & (-0.387229 * \mathit{LBIO5}) + \\
                & (0.186574 * \mathit{LCOKLM}) + \\
                & (-0.110286 * \mathit{LRUNOFF}) + \\
                & (0.175157 * \mathit{WATRGRC}) + \\
                & (-0.743144 * \mathit{PERWLTG}) + \\
                & (0.004706 * \mathit{RLOW}) + \\
                & (-0.080339 * \mathit{RUNGRC}) + \\
                & (0.024755 * \mathit{SDTEMP})]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

It's the result of stepwise multiple regression on a complex dataset. The variables represent different biological, geographical and ethnographical values. An example: LCOKLM is the log10 value of the distance of a hunter-gatherer group from the marine coast.

The form of this equation confuses me. How can I transform it to a more readable format, that allows me to compare the coefficients? I would like to have it in a form that lets me read the intercept and the slopes to compare the model with the output of the R function `lm()`.

Comment: (1) Make a table of the coefficients. (2) Round the values.  (I am *certain* that no dataset about ethnographical values supports estimation of regression coefficients to six significant figures!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion in (2) - that's very relevant. About (1): How do I exactly do this? Probably I'm suffering from a very general thick-headedness but I think I need a formula of the following form to create this table: Y = a + b1*X1 + b2*X2 + ... + bp*Xp

Comment: To compare coefficients, tabulate the coefficients.  This would be essentially the same thing as the output of `coef(fit)` where `fit` is the object returned by `lm`.

Comment: That's not the difficult part for me... How do I read... let's say... the intercept from this equation?

Comment: The intercept is 3.421431, in the sense that this is a model for the common logarithm of `Area`.

Comment: Aha! So if `Area = 10^x` then `log Area = x`! Thanks. That's it. Is there a simple reason, why Binford could have decided to calculate a model for `log AREA` instead of area? Is the log scale better for the regression? But I guess that's already another question. Thanks a lot!